# Nested TreeMap - Value is being stored in a single Key

Tags: java

Is the first time that I'm trying to implement a TreeMap.  In this case I have the following data that is retreived through iteration:

```
A
    a
    shape:square
    fill:yes
    size:very large
B
    b
        shape:square
        fill:yes
        size:very large
C
    c
        shape:square
        fill:yes
        size:very large
```

I need to store this data in TreeMaps. An example would be a TreeMap(A, TreeMap(a, Treemap(keySize, sizeAttribute)))

I implemented this:

```
Map<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>> squareRPM = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>>(); //Everytime it changes object create a new squareRPM
            TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> component = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>();  
            TreeMap<String, String> CompAttr = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

In the iteration I have:

```
        for(String figureName : problem.getFigures().keySet()) {  //Iterates through the Name of figures as A, B, C, 1...6
        RavensFigure thisFigure = problem.getFigures().get(figureName);

        for(String objectName : thisFigure.getObjects().keySet()) { //Iterates through components in each A, B, C Ex.  A a 
        RavensObject thisObject = thisFigure.getObjects().get(objectName);


        for(String attributeName : thisObject.getAttributes().keySet()) {  //Iterates through attributes 
        String attributeValue = thisObject.getAttributes().get(attributeName);

        CompAttr.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
        component.put(objectName, CompAttr);
        squareRPM.put(figureName, component);
        }            
    }       

}

        System.out.println(squareRPM.get("A")) ;
```

The output I want is:

```
[A={a={fill=yes, shape=square, size=very large}}]
[B={b={fill=yes, shape=square, size=very large}}]
```

But instead I have this:

```
[A={a={fill=yes, shape=square, size=very large},b ={fill=yes, shape=square, size=very large},c={fill=yes, shape=square, size=very large}}]
```

Everything is being stored in A.  How can I solve this?

Thank you.

---

Solved it!

```
        for(String figureName : problem.getFigures().keySet()) {  //Iterates through the Name of figures as A, B, C, 1...6
        RavensFigure thisFigure = problem.getFigures().get(figureName);
        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>> squareRPM = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>>(); //Everytime it changes object create a new squareRPM    

        for(String objectName : thisFigure.getObjects().keySet()) { //Iterates through components in each A, B, C Ex.  A a 
        RavensObject thisObject = thisFigure.getObjects().get(objectName);
        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> component = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>();  
        TreeMap<String, String> CompAttr = new TreeMap<String, String>();    

        for(String attributeName : thisObject.getAttributes().keySet()) {  //Iterates through attributes 
        String attributeValue = thisObject.getAttributes().get(attributeName);


        CompAttr.put(attributeName, attributeValue);

        }       
        component.put(objectName, CompAttr);
        squareRPM.put(figureName, component);
```

//

```
        for(Entry<String, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>> entry : squareRPM.entrySet()) {

              String key = entry.getKey();
              TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> value = entry.getValue();

              System.out.println(key + " => " + value);

        }
    }       

}
```

The problem was were I was creating each TreeMap >.>

Comment: Placing a Map in a Map in a Map is generally a bad idea as it confuses everybody. Implement own classes with a clear naming. Those classes can internally use a Map of other custom classes (which can contain a Map again).

Comment: Yes I thought of building classes, but I'm new to Java and this was the first attempt to try to put the attributes in a place were I can compare them.  I'll give a try to your suggestion.  Thank you very much! I doubted that it could be made.